# is there a vim plugin to provide autocompletion for related but separate javascript files

Tags: javascript, vim

I'm looking for a vim plugin that would do autocompletion not only for the expressions already present in the current file, but for files related to it as well.

I don't know what are the possibilities, but my best guess would be something where I give the path to an html file that includes my file, and vim checks all the relates  tags, and provides autocompletion using all of them.

do you know about anything similar?

For vim config, it seems that I've settled with [mutewinter's Vim configuration](https://github.com/mutewinter/dot_vim)

thanks, Viktor

Answer (score 0):

Use `tags` (`:help tags`) generated by [Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or some other JavaScript-specific tools like [DoctorJS](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs)'s `jsctags`. Supposing you have an up-to-date and reachable `tags` file, `<C-x><C-]>` will use it as completion source and allow you to complete method names found in other files.

Be aware that it's not at all as smart as what IDEs do.